# Sum of column containing nan and inf as values in SQL

Tags: postgresql, questdb

I am using QuestDB and one column has values double e.g. 10.5, 5.2 etc, but few rows come like -nan, inf for not a number and infinity.
What is the best way to sum this column. If I do normal sum it fails with casting problem due to nan and inf rows.

I can also use PostgreSQL if you think it can be solved in that.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try the [KSUM](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/aggregation/#ksum) function .

Alternatively, you could always use [COALESCE](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/conditional/#coalesce) to turn nulls into Zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

Could you explain 'how normal sum fails with casting problem' ?

In QuestDB sum(double) skips null and NaN values but includes +/-Infinity.

Example (with psql because Web Console shows Infinities as null):

```
create table data ( d double);
insert into data values  (null), (NaN), (0);
select sum(d) from data;
 sum 
-----
 0.0    
(1 row)
```

Now, if we add Infinity:

```
insert into data values  ('Infinity');
select sum(d) from data;
   sum    
----------
 Infinity
(1 row)
```

What happens if we add -Infinity ?

```
insert into data values  ('-Infinity');
select sum(d) from data; sum 
-----
    
(1 row)
```

we get null, which is the same as NaN in QuestDB (see [DATA TYPES](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/datatypes/)), because we try to add -Infinity and +Infinity and that can't return a sensible result.

In addition to what Javier mentioned above, you also can skip Infinities with `is not null`:

```
select sum(d) from data where d is not null;
 sum 
-----
 0.0
(1 row)
```